# Tensor decomposition of 2-way array

Tags: r, tensor, decomposition

I can use `rTensor::cp` to decompose a 3-way array in `R`. However an error would occur for decomposing a 2-way array `L[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`. How to decompose a 2-way array? Thanks.

`cp` works well for a 3-way array.

```r
library(rTensor)
a <- c(0.1,0.9)
b <- c(0.5,0.5)
c <- c(0.7,0.3)
tnsr <- as.tensor(outer(outer(a,b),c))
cpD <- cp(tnsr, num_components=1)

> $U[[1]]
>      [,1]
> [1,]  0.1
> [2,]  0.9

> $U[[2]]
>      [,1]
> [1,] -0.5
> [2,] -0.5

> $U[[3]]
>      [,1]
> [1,] -0.7
> [2,] -0.3
```

An error occurs for a 2-way array.

```r
tnsr <- as.tensor(outer(a,b))
cpD <- cp(tnsr, num_components=1)

> Error in L[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: I realised that a normal PCA would be sufficient for the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to multiply the 2-way array by 1 to make it a 3-way array.

```
tnsr = as.tensor(outer(outer(a,b),1))
cpD = cp(tnsr, num_components=1)

> $U[[1]]
>      [,1]
> [1,]  0.1
> [2,]  0.9

> $U[[2]]
>      [,1]
> [1,] -0.5
> [2,] -0.5

> $U[[3]]
>      [,1]
> [1,]   -1
```